# Cannot find jar in MVNrepository

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-central

I have successfully published the jar to Maven Central https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, and I can also use it in my project, but why I can't find it in MVNrepository https://mvnrepository.com.
Here is the jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.phantom0103</groupId>
  <artifactId>elem-open-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: mvnrepository update cycle is not known so it can take a while. What about  using https://search.maven.org/

Comment: It can be able to search in search.maven.org soon. Almost 24 hours have passed, and I still can’t search in MVNrepository.

Comment: I successfully found it at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.phantom0103/elem-open-sdk .

Comment: Haha, I also found it now. 